# Keyboard shortcut to launch Konsole in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, system-settings

I recently installed Konsole in my Ubuntu 16.04. I want to be able to launch Konsole using keyboard shortcut similar to Terminal. I tried adding shortcut in System Settings, but it did not work.

[image: Konsole]

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please run `which konsole` and post output.

Answer (score 1):

Click the icon in the very top-right of the screen to open system preferences, the go to the subsection labelled "Keyboard". Once there, click on the "Shortcuts" tab and use the following steps to add as many custom shortcuts as you like!

1. Click the plus sign to add a new shortcut
2. Fill in the name you want to remember it by, and the actual command
   in the command field (in this case, the command is console).
3. Click where it will say "Disabled" to set the hotkey you like (I
   used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).
4. Press the hotkey to open Konsole (in my case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

[image: Steps]

Answer (score 1):

To set up a short key for konsole do the following or check that you did:

1. Install it with:

   ```
   sudo apt install konsole
   ```
2. Run `which konsole` to determine the command that launches it, result should be:

   ```
   /usr/bin/konsole
   ```
3. Open `system settings` and after selecting `custom shortcuts` enter `/usr/bin/konsole` as the command to launch it.

   [image]
4. Close that dialogue box and click on the `disabled` text and **use your keyboard** to enter your desired shut (which should not conflict with standard Ubuntu keyboard shutcuts) and your done.
5. Test it out.